# SimpleJavaMail: Where is dkimPrivateKey from?

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail, dkim

I am using [Simple Java Mail](http://www.simplejavamail.org/) to send emails signed with DKIM. Simple Java Mail offers this method in class

```
public EmailPopulatingBuilder signWithDomainKey(
     @Nonnull
     String dkimPrivateKey,
     @Nonnull
     String signingDomain,
     @Nonnull
     String dkimSelector)
```

I would like to know where and how to get dkimPrivateKey in the method. According to online information, I need to run something like the following (in Windows Prompt) to generate private key:

```
openssl genrsa -out dkim.pem 1024 (this generates a file dkim.pem)

openssl pkcs8 -topk8 -nocrypt -in dkim.pem -outform der -out dkim.der  (this generates a file dkim.der)
```

dkim.pem is a text file with a RSA private key. dkim.der is a binary file and so I cannot copy it directly into a Java program.

Comment: if you are talking about http://www.simplejavamail.org/features.html then you do not need to pass the private key as string. 

And also http://www.simplejavamail.org/modules.html#dkim-module this give you some reference for DKIM library

Comment: Thanks for your input! I understand that I can pass the private key through other approaches such as file. In my case, I need to pass it as a string.

Comment: Also take a look at the [test package](https://github.com/bbottema/simple-java-mail/tree/develop/modules/simple-java-mail/src/test/resources/pkcs12) which deals with all this. Specifically check "about all this.txt" and "how-to.html".